# dynamic generate byte with asm

Tags: tomcat, jvm, classloader, bytecode

I use the asm to implements a proxy patterns. 
for example:
the original class is test.service.Service

```
public class ProxyFactory{
    public static Object generateProxy(Class<?> argument){
        //do generate use asm. 
        //generate a proxyClass that extends argument
        //and override the sayHello() method
        //and than invoke System.out.println("anything") before we call super.sayHello()
        Class<?> class = proxyClass;
        return class.newInstance();
    }
}


public class Service implements IService{
    @Override
    public List<String> sayHello(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("stackoverflow user");
        return list;
    }
}

public class Action extends ActionSupport{

     private IService service = ProxyFactory.generateProxy(Service.class);

}
```

When I request this action than will be an Exception:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test.service.Service
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    ...
    ... 40 more 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.service.Service
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ...
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 43 more

It's seem like tomcat classloader problem because all above code can work if I run it as application could you anybody help me to solve it.
  Thank

Comment: Please update your code example with detail on how you get instance of proxyClass and also post the full stack trace (the one you've posted doesn't look related to your example, e.g. I don't see generateProxy() method call in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve by myself, actually , As I expected, the problem is caused by classloader.
this is before code:

```
byte[] b = class byte code...
ClassLoder loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader");
java.lang.reflect.Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod(
                "defineClass", new Class[] { String.class, byte[].class,
                        int.class, int.class });
method.setAccessible(true);
Object[] args = new Object[] { sc.getName(), b, new Integer(0),
                    new Integer(b.length) };
clazz = (Class<?>) method.invoke(loader, args);
```

and now i use Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() to instead of 
 ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

it mean we can use tomcat classloader to defined our class so than can found our web 
 application class "test.service.Service"